# Дата в PHP и MySQL

Tags: дата, php, mysql

В PHP скрипте я сохраняю дату вида ГГГГ-ММ-ДД ЧЧ:ММ:СС в переменную $date:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Затем пытаюсь записать переменную $date в базу данных в поле date со значением DATETIME:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO users (id, username, email, password, 'date')
                    VALUES(0, '$username', '$email', SHA1('$password'), $date)";
```

Но постоянно выскакивает ошибка:

> `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''date') VALUES(0, 'lol', 'lol', SHA1('lol'), 2012-05-26 01:20:52)' at line 1`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

В запросе переменную $date возмите в одинарные кавычки, а название поля date - без кавычек.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (id, username, email, password, date)
                    VALUES(0, '$username', '$email', SHA1('$password'), '$date')";
```

Спали бы вы по ночам )))

Comment: я бы посоветовал поле date обрамлять апострофами: `date`

Comment: стоит так же добавить что данные нужно экранировать.

Comment: @Deonis, и вам, думаю, стоит спать по ночам =)))

Comment: @Аsen, эх, да я б с удовольствием, вот только когда ж работать, если днём дети на голове висят? ;)

Comment: Тонко подмечено. Можно сидеть ночь и элементарной ошибки не увидеть, а поспать и за 5 минут исправить. На личном опыте.

Answer (score 4):

Вообще, дату в базе нужно хранить в виде результата функции `time()`.

При чтении данных из базы дата будет формироваться при помощи функции `date("d/m/Y", $time)`;